# Show the total sale in Hourly basis for a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to generate a sales report for a date range in which user will select day -start hour and day- end hour.

The below query will return date-time and amount of sale

```
select s.StartDate ,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(OrigionalSubTotal)/100.0) Amt from Sale s
    where 
    s.StartDate
    BETWEEN '2016-06-12 04:00:01'
     and    '2016-06-18 04:00:00' 
     and s.IsSuspend = 0  and s.IsTrainMode = 0 and wasrefunded=0
    and IsCancelled = 0
    group by S.StartDate
    order by s.StartDate
```

O/p

```
 StartDate                Amt
2016-06-12 10:01:15.780    10.00
2016-06-12 10:15:57.360    20.00
2016-06-12 12:48:41.250    50.00
2016-06-13 11:02:50.850    5.00
2016-06-13 12:04:45.090    15.00
2016-06-14 14:18:38.960    10.00
```

From this I need to take hourly sales as below for the date range 12-June-16 to 18-June-16

```
From -To       Sun-12   Mon-13  Tue-14  Wed-15  Thu-16  Fri-17  Sat-18
04:00-05:00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00--nosale
05:00-06:00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00      "
06:00-07:00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00      "
07:00-08:00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00      "
08:00-09:00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00      "
09:00-10:00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00      "
10:00-11:00    30.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
11:00-12:00    0.00     5.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
12:00-13:00    50.00    15.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
13:00-14:00    0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
14:00-15:00    0.00     0.00    10.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
..
..
..
23:00-00:00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
..
..
03:00-04:00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

How can I achieve the same from above table. Please show some light on this. I am totally stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preparing report structure

Sales data does not have records for each hour in every day of period given. So to obtain required structure with all "trade day" (or whatever you call it)  hours and each date of period given you'll have to provide list of time intervals and weekdays to your script from somewhere else (since Sales stores only some data).

So you'll need list of time intervals and list of dates (weekdays).
After that you'll be able to make `LEFT JOIN` and get *data from Sales* or NULL if no appropriate data exists.

Your approach is based on simple `GROUP BY` - that's why you can not get any other rows except those you have in `dbo.Sales`.

And if I understood your request right - you are building something like *"weekly report"* and my solution is based on this assumption (that you'll always need 7 days only).

## Aggregating data

Now, to produce required output you need *dates from rows to become columns*. This can be accomplished by `PIVOT` (or `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` trick).
Without pivoting output of `time+date left join sales` would look like:

```
[From-To]    [Date]       [Amt]
10:00-11:00   12.06 (Sun)  11
10:00-11:00   13.06 (Mon)  5
```

After `PIVOT` you will have dates (weekdays) as columns but many rows for same time period - from different days:

```
[From-To]    [Sun] [Mon]
10:00-11:00    11     0
10:00-11:00     0     5
```

So you'll have to aggregate it

```
[From-To]    [Sun] [Mon]
10:00-11:00    11     5
```

which can be done by simple `GROUP BY`

## Source

Recursive CTE is used here to populate `@Timing` and `@WeekDays` tables with sequential data (note `+1` and `dateadd` there).

One of the easiest and often suggested ways to work with such data as lists of periods of time or calendar dates is to populate persistent `Calendar` table with everything you need. Then - just select from it to get all days of period given.

Another side note: your trade day starts not at 0:00 so you'll probably need to understand which of 4:00 belongs to this astronomy day and which - to the next. At list you'll need to get those rows in right order. See `hrs` column in code below which stores hours from 4 to 27.

If my assumption of "weekly report" is wrong and you need a report with dynamic number of columns then the only way to get it is to use dynamic sql.

```
declare
  @DateBegin  datetime = '20160612',
  @DateEnd    datetime = '20160615'

declare @Sales table
(
  StartDate datetime,
  OrigionalSubTotal decimal(10, 2)
)

insert into @Sales(StartDate, OrigionalSubTotal)
values
('2016-06-12 10:01:15.780',    10.00),
('2016-06-12 10:15:57.360',    20.00),
('2016-06-12 12:48:41.250',    50.00),
('2016-06-13 11:02:50.850',    5.00),
('2016-06-13 12:04:45.090',    15.00),
('2016-06-14 14:18:38.960',    10.00)

/* DEBUG: * /
select * from @Sales
/ * :DEBUG */

declare @Timing table
(
  hrs smallint,
  hours_start smallint,
  hours_end   smallint,
  period varchar(11)
)

;with cteTiming as
(
  select 4 as hrs

  union all

  select t.hrs+1
  from cteTiming t
  where t.hrs < 27
)
insert into @Timing (hrs, hours_start, hours_end, period)
select t.hrs, hrs % 24, (hrs + 1) % 24, 
  cast(hrs % 24 as varchar(10)) + ':00-' + cast((hrs+1) % 24 as varchar(10)) + ':00'
from cteTiming t

/* DEBUG: * /
select * from @Timing
/ * :DEBUG */

declare @WeekDays table
(
  wd smallint,
  wd_name varchar(3),
  wd_date date
)

;with cteWeekDays as
(
  select
    1 wd,
    dateadd(day, 1-datepart(weekday, @DateBegin), cast(@DateBegin as date)) wd_date

  union all

  select
    wd.wd+1,
    dateadd(day, 1, wd.wd_date) wd_date
  from cteWeekDays wd
  where wd.wd < 7
)
insert into @WeekDays (wd, wd_name, wd_date)
select wd.wd, left(datename(weekday, wd.wd_date), 3), wd.wd_date
from cteWeekDays wd

/* DEBUG: * /
select * from @WeekDays
/ * :DEBUG */

;with cteSales as
(
  select
    datepart(weekday, s.StartDate) as SalesWeekDay,
    datediff(hour, cast(s.StartDate as date), s.StartDate) DayTime,
    cast(s.StartDate as date) SalesDate,
    s.OrigionalSubTotal
  from @Sales s
  where s.StartDate >= @DateBegin and s.StartDate < @DateEnd
),
cteSalesPerWeekDays as
(
  select
    p.hrs,
    p.period,
    p.[Mon], p.[Tue], p.[Wed], p.[Thu], p.[Fri], p.[Sat], p.[Sun]
  from @Timing t
  cross join @WeekDays w
  left join cteSales s on s.DayTime >= t.hours_start and s.DayTime < t.hours_end
    and s.SalesDate = w.wd_date
  pivot
  (
    Sum(s.OrigionalSubTotal)
    for w.wd_name in ([Mon], [Tue], [Wed], [Thu], [Fri], [Sat], [Sun])
  ) p
)
select
  spd.hrs,
  spd.period as [From-To],
  Sum(IsNull(spd.[Sun], 0)) as [Sun],
  Sum(IsNull(spd.[Mon], 0)) as [Mon],
  Sum(IsNull(spd.[Tue], 0)) as [Tue],
  Sum(IsNull(spd.[Wed], 0)) as [Wed],
  Sum(IsNull(spd.[Thu], 0)) as [Thu],
  Sum(IsNull(spd.[Fri], 0)) as [Fri],
  Sum(IsNull(spd.[Sat], 0)) as [Sat]
from cteSalesPerWeekDays spd
group by spd.hrs, spd.period
order by spd.hrs
```

[image]

## Deploying

To move from sample `@Sales` table to real source you'll need to replace it in first cte of final select with this (part of your script):

```
;with cteSales as
(
  select
    datepart(weekday, s.StartDate) as SalesWeekDay,
    datediff(hour, cast(s.StartDate as date), s.StartDate) DayTime,
    cast(s.StartDate as date) SalesDate,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),sum(OrigionalSubTotal)/100.0) as OrigionalSubTotal
  from dbo.Sales s
  where s.StartDate >= @DateBegin and s.StartDate < @DateEnd
    and s.IsSuspend = 0  and s.IsTrainMode = 0
    and s.IsCancelled = 0 and s.wasrefunded=0
 )
 ...
```

But @WeekDays and @Timing will stay! You need it to produce report structure needed.

Note, `s.StartDate` contains time so simple date filter like `between` won't work in some cases (for upper date). Suggested way is to filter `>=` for start date and `<` *next date after given period upper bound with zero time*. This way you'll find all '23:59:59' for sure.

And note that I have changed the order of weekdays in pivot. Actually, after the `PIVOT` there is no difference of column order - it should be managed by client-side app. Or by the final select statement as in example above. All other code is aware of whether your week starts with Sunday or Monday.

## UPD: Dynamic number of days

And fixed date filter for 00:00-04:00 period of next astronomy day. I added some rows to demonstrate it.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Sales', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #Sales')
GO
if object_id('tempdb..#Timing', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #Timing')
GO
if object_id('tempdb..#WeekDays', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #WeekDays')
GO
declare
  @DateBegin    datetime = '20160612',
  @DateEnd      datetime = '20160715',
  @TradeDateEnd datetime

/* to enable "<" filter */
set @TradeDateEnd = dateadd(hour, 4, dateadd(day, 1, @DateEnd))

declare
  @sql                    nvarchar(max),
  @col_per_day_list       nvarchar(max),
  @pivot_val_per_day_list nvarchar(max),
  @sum_cols_per_day_list  nvarchar(max)

create table #Sales
(
  StartDate datetime,
  OrigionalSubTotal decimal(10, 2)
)

insert into #Sales(StartDate, OrigionalSubTotal)
values
('20160612 03:55:00.000',    77.00),
('20160612 10:01:15.780',    10.00),
('20160612 10:15:57.360',    20.00),
('20160612 12:48:41.250',    50.00),
('20160613 11:02:50.850',     5.00),
('20160613 12:04:45.090',    15.00),
('20160614 14:18:38.960',    10.00),
('20160715 17:22:00.000',    11.00),
('20160716 03:55:00.000',    99.00)

/* DEBUG: * /
select * from #Sales
/ * :DEBUG */

create table #Timing
(
  hrs smallint,
  hours_start smallint,
  hours_end   smallint,
  period varchar(11)
)

;with cteTiming as
(
  select 4 as hrs

  union all

  select t.hrs+1
  from cteTiming t
  where t.hrs < 27
)
insert into #Timing (hrs, hours_start, hours_end, period)
select t.hrs, hrs % 24, (hrs + 1) % 24, 
  cast(hrs % 24 as varchar(10)) + ':00-' + cast((hrs+1) % 24 as varchar(10)) + ':00'
from cteTiming t

/* DEBUG: * /
select * from #Timing
/ * :DEBUG */

create table #WeekDays
(
  wd smallint,
  wd_date datetime,
  wd_name varchar(12)
)

;with cteWeekDays as
(
  select
    datepart(weekday, @DateBegin) wd,
    cast(@DateBegin as date) wd_date

  union all

  select
    wd.wd+1,
    dateadd(day, 1, wd.wd_date) wd_date
  from cteWeekDays wd
  where wd_date < cast(@DateEnd as date)
)
insert into #WeekDays (wd, wd_date, wd_name)
select wd.wd, wd.wd_date,
  left(datename(weekday, wd.wd_date), 3) + '-' + convert(varchar(8), wd.wd_date, 112)
from cteWeekDays wd

/* DEBUG: * /
select * from #WeekDays
/ * :DEBUG */

select
  @sum_cols_per_day_list = stuff(wd.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
from
  (
    select
      ',
  Sum(IsNull(r.' + quotename(wd.wd_name) + ', 0)) as ' + quotename(wd.wd_name)
    from #WeekDays wd
    order by wd.wd_date
    for xml path(''), type
  ) x(wd)

select
  @col_per_day_list = stuff(wd.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
from
  (
    select
      ',
    p.' + quotename(wd.wd_name)
    from #WeekDays wd
    order by wd.wd_date
    for xml path(''), type
  ) x(wd)

set @pivot_val_per_day_list = replace(@col_per_day_list, 'p.[', '  [')

/* DEBUG: * /
print @col_per_day_list
print @pivot_val_per_day_list
print @sum_cols_per_day_list
/ * :DEBUG */

set @sql = cast(N'
;with cteSales as
(
  select
    datepart(weekday, s.StartDate) as SalesWeekDay,
    datediff(hour, cast(s.StartDate as date), s.StartDate) DayTime,
    s.StartDate SalesDate,
    s.OrigionalSubTotal
  from #Sales s
  where s.StartDate >= @DateBegin and s.StartDate < @DateEnd
),
cteSalesPerWeekDays as
(
  select
    p.hrs,
    p.period,' as nvarchar(max)) + @col_per_day_list + N'
  from #Timing t
  cross join #WeekDays w
  left join cteSales s on datediff(hour, w.wd_date, s.SalesDate) = t.hrs
  pivot
  (
    Sum(s.OrigionalSubTotal)
    for w.wd_name in (' + @pivot_val_per_day_list + N')
  ) p
)
select
  r.hrs,
  r.period as [From-To],' + @sum_cols_per_day_list + N'
from cteSalesPerWeekDays r
group by r.hrs, r.period
order by r.hrs
'
/* DEBUG: */
print left(@sql, 4000)
print substring(@sql, 4000, 4000)
print datalength(@sql) / 2
/* :DEBUG */

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@DateBegin datetime, @DateEnd datetime',
  @DateBegin = @DateBegin,
  @DateEnd = @TradeDateEnd

GO
if object_id('tempdb..#Sales', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #Sales')
GO
if object_id('tempdb..#Timing', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #Timing')
GO
if object_id('tempdb..#WeekDays', 'U') is not NULL
  exec('drop table #WeekDays')
GO
```

Solution is almost the same except you need to collect column list before building final select and `@` tables can't be used because their scope is limited to current batch.

`FOR XML` stuff guaranties right order of column list generated.

[image]

For dynamic number of days you will also need month and year in column names (for example if one wants to build report from last days of December till January of next year).

## upd2

- fixed cteWeekDays to avoid starting always from first day of week and make it begin from `@DateBegin` given
- introduced `@TradeDateEnd` to keep `@DateEnd` unchanged

## upd3

- additional column from Sales in output

*reverted*

Comment: its not always 7 days..it can be dynamic..thats why after sun the date 12 is attaching

Comment: so if i need to remove` @sales` and put dbo.sales just remove `@sales `code and put dbo.sales table in first CTE right?

Comment: now the column always start from sunday..is it possible to start from the day of the date chosen to 7 days? eg if the date chosen in tuesday..then tue,wed,...mon..im saying about non dynamic.7 column report

Comment: @Sachu as you're saying _"when parameter is...then columns are..."_ - this is definitely _dynamic_ query building.

Comment: yes..but in the dynamic query solution if i give start date as '20160615' and end date as '20160616' only two columns are generating but the data is 'sun-20160612' and 'mon-20160613' not 'wed-20160615' and 'thu-20160616'

Comment: @Sachu yeah, right, I forgot to remove that `dateadd(day, 1-datepart(weekday, @DateBegin), cast(@DateBegin as date)) wd_date` from cteWeekDays. Couple of minutes.

Comment: @Sachu see upd2. Couple of lines fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115648/discussion-between-sachu-and-ivan-starostin).

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot might be what you are looking for. For Example

```
declare @s table(FromTo varchar(11),Sun12 decimal(10,2),  Mon13 decimal(10,2),  Tue14 decimal(10,2),  Wed15 decimal(10,2) ,Thu16 decimal(10,2), Fri17 decimal(10,2), Sat18 decimal(10,2))
insert into @s
values
('04:00-05:00' ,   0.00  ,   0.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('05:00-06:00' ,   0.00  ,   0.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('06:00-07:00' ,   0.00  ,   0.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('07:00-08:00' ,   0.00  ,   0.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('08:00-09:00' ,   0.00  ,   0.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('09:00-10:00' ,   0.00  ,   0.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('10:00-11:00' ,   30.00 ,   0.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('11:00-12:00' ,   0.00  ,   5.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('12:00-13:00' ,   50.00 ,   15.00,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('13:00-14:00' ,   0.00  ,   0.00 ,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00),
('14:00-15:00' ,   0.00  ,   0.00 ,   10.00,   0.00,    0.00,    0.00,    0.00)

;WITH CTE AS
(
select  UPVT.fromto,UPVT.DD,UPVT.sales
from    
( SELECT FROMTO,Sun12,  Mon13,  Tue14,  Wed15 ,Thu16, Fri17, Sat18 FROM @S) P
unpivot (sales for DD in (Sun12,  Mon13,  Tue14,  Wed15 ,Thu16, Fri17, Sat18)
)  UPVT
)
SELECT   DD,CTE.FROMTO, SUM(CTE.SALES) SALES
FROM    CTE
GROUP   BY  DD,CTE.FROMTO HAVING SUM(CTE.SALES) > 0
order   by  cast(right(DD,2) as int),CTE.FROMTO
```